# Invalid surface in VideoView callback

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview

I have a TabbedActivity, which has 2 tabs. Each tab has its own activity, and the activities  do video playback. I want to access the underlying surface for the VideoViews in these activities, and hence I implemented SurfaceHolder.Callback, as shown here:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e(TAG,"surfaceChanged "+ holder+" format "+format+" w "+width+" h "+height);
    if (holder.getSurface().isValid())
        Log.e(TAG,"holder has a valid surface");
    else
        Log.e(TAG,"holder has an invalid surface");     
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (holder.getSurface().isValid())
        Log.e(TAG,"holder has a valid surface");
    else
        Log.e(TAG,"holder has an invalid surface");
    mHolder = holder;

}
```

When I run this code, the callbacks always show that the surfaceholder has an invalid surface. So, whatever I do on the surface with mHolder.getSurface() is going into a NULL surface. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance